# SQL оптимизация запроса

Tags: sql

Допустим, у меня есть таблица с пользователями, которые разделены по группам. Есть колонки `user_id, group_id, info`. Может пример немного неудачный, но вопрос такой: Стоит ли добавлять в запрос дополнительный параметр, если он известен? Быстрее или медленнее выполнится второй вариант запроса? Что изменится если вместо user_id мы возьмем не индексированный столбец? Или что произойдет, если оба столбца будут неиндексированы?

```
1) select info from users where user_id = 3;
2) select info from users where group_id = 4 and user_id = 3;
```

Comment: Запросы неэквивалентны, поэтому сравнение некорректно. Если предположить, что для `user_id = 3` существует только одна запись, и в ней `group_id = 4`, то второй запрос выполнится быстрее первого лишь в случае, когда есть индекс `(group_id, user_id)`, нет индекса `(user_id)`, и оптимизатор решит, что использование индекса выгоднее прямого сканирования таблицы. А также в случае, когда для первого запроса оптимизатор решит не использовать индекс, а для второго - будет использовать индекс (причём любой).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У разных SQL-серверов может быть своя специфика, но, как правило, для второго запроса поиск идет по следующему алгоритму.

1) Ищутся индексы по всем сочетаниям столбцов, участвующих в отборе. В данном случае это по id_user, по id_group, и по паре id_user,id_group.

2) При наличии, из найденных выбирается уникальный индекс. Если уникального нет, то выбирается тот, у которого наибольшая селективность (наибольшее количество разных значений).

3) Если ни одного индекса не найдено или селективность очень низкая (например только два различных значения), то используется полный перебор всех строк.

Например, если по id_user есть уникальный индекс, то запросы будут эквивалентны по плану.

Если же индекс есть только по id_group, то второй будет эффективнее, т.к. будут перебираться не все записи, а только те, у которых id_group = 4.